# why can't I add i plus a random integer in for loop?

Tags: java

Could some one please explain to me why I can't 5 to i? Every time I try to compile, I get an error saying it is not a statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s; i+5) {

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i + 5` alone doesn't modify `i`. You still have to change `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s; i += 5) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do what @Blender suggests is as so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s; i=i+5) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of i is not being increased by i+5. 
Try this

```
for (int i=0;i<s ;i=i+5 ){

}
```

or

```
for(int i=0;i<s;i+=5){

}
```